# Why does Spark keep saying "UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment" on a correct code?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have some trouble with Spark. When I'm trying to run a function in Spark, it keeps saying `"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'min2' referenced before assignment"`. However, my code runs with no problem on other computers.

The code is as below:

```
numbers = [1,2,7,9,3,1,4,9,10,10,11] 

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(numbers)

def find_min_max(partition):
    first_time = False
    for v in partition:
        if first_time == False:
            min2 = v
            max2 = v
            first_time = True
        else:
            min2 = min(min2, v)
            max2 = max(max2, v)
    return [(min2, max2)]

min_max = rdd.mapPartitions(find_min_max)
```

Spark reports the error when I call "min_max.collect()".
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'min2' referenced before assignment`

If I add `"min2 = 0 max2 = 0"` before and outside the for-loop, the code can run, but the output is not correct. The output will be

```
[(0, 0),
 (1, 1),
 (2, 2),
 (7, 7),
 (9, 9),
 (3, 3),
 (1, 1),
 (4, 4),
 (9, 9),
 (10, 10),
 (10, 10),
 (11, 11)]
```

The output contains an extra 0 and it seems not to be partitioned.

Could anyone help me with this issue?

PS: Spark version is 3.0.0 and Python version is 3.7.6

Comment: In the `else` case `min2` is not set before it is used.

Comment: If you run the function on an empty input, you'd never set the variables before trying to return them.

Comment: @KlausD. It only goes to `else` from the 2nd iteration and afterward. At that time `min2` would already be set, right? Also, this code snippet was able to run through by several of my classmates (literally the same code snippet).

Comment: @Blckknght could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I don't know what `mapPartitions` does, but if you test your function with `find_min_max([])`, you'll get the same error you describe. I'd guess that when it gets called from `mapPartitions`, it gets the equivalent argument at least once.